# Mysql2::Error: Incorrect table name '' - when using AppMap Gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

I recently found out about the [AppMap](https://appmap.io/) utility and I'm trying to incorporate it into my Rails app via IntelliJ. However, after installing the gem and configuring it, any request I make results throws the following exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#index

Mysql2::Error: Incorrect table name ''
```

It does this for every page, model, request, etc. when using a browser. From my stack trace, it looks like the issue is arising when the roles are being checked in my `Ability.rb` file (I'm using `Devise`, `CanCanCan`, and `Rolify` for authentication).

If I try to do `user.roles` in the rails console it produces this:

```
irb(main):007:0> u.roles
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `` ON `roles`.`id` = ``.`role_id` WHERE ``.`user_id` = 1
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

If I remove the `AppMap` gem then everything in my application works as intended like it has been previously.

I'm not really sure where to go from here so any input would be greatly appreciated!

**Versions:**

- IntelliJ IDEA: 2022.1.4 (Ultimate)
- AppMap Plugin: 0.21.0
- AppMap Gem: 0.94.1
- Rails: 6.1.4.7
- Ruby: 3.0.1
- MySql2: 0.5.4
- CanCaCan: 3.2.2
- Devise: 4.8.1
- Rolify: 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this in the AppMap [github issues page](https://github.com/getappmap/appmap-ruby/issues/302).  This issue is resolved in `v0.95.0` of the appmap-ruby gem.  If you need any other help just open another issue or join us in our [community slack](https://appmap.io/slack)